# CSS Loading in IE9 but not IE11 using IE9 emulation mode

Tags: css, internet-explorer-11

I have a really strange issue that has me pulling my hair out. When I load a web page in IE9 the CSS renders perfectly fine. The page also renders fine in firefox and chrome.

However when I try to render the page in IE11 using a document mode of 9 several CSS files are not being applied. This is also the case if the document mode is 10 but it works fine using "Edge"

I have monitored the network traffic and can confirm that the CSS files are being pulled down.

Any ideas what might be causing this?

Comment: Hello! Is there maybe a pic available?

Comment: Very hard to tell without any example or code

Comment: do you have a link to a working page for debugging purposes?

Comment: Unfortunately, as this is for a customer I will be unable to provide these.

Comment: The emulation is not perfect, but should cover most cases like conditional comments and the like. Only thing I can think of here are CSS hacks - intentionally wrong written CSS rules that exploit bugs in certain browser versions. Some libraries like bootstrap use those.

Answer (score 0):

Eventually during a discussion with a colleague it was discovered that this issue was being caused by SharePoint and not IE11. The problem was that the file was UTF-8 encoded and needed to be ANSI encoded and subsequently was not being served correctly for whatever reason.

Answer (score 0):

For me the answer was to add this with my existing conditional comments...

```
<!--[if !IE]><!--><script type="text/javascript">if(/*@cc_on!@*/false){document.documentElement.className += 'ie10';}</script><!--<![endif]-->
```

Why it only works when I add that I'm not sure, currently using a HTML5 doctype and no additional styling is given with the class ie10, it's literally there for feature detection purposes only.

I had tried giving the CSS a different encoding (ANSI & UTF-8) like other answers have said, also tried using a XHTML 4.0 doctype incase it was caused by the HTML5 doctype but nope.

Also ensured the IIS 7.0 server did accept the text/css MIME.